# iOS wait for connection to get data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, synchronous

I have a class with a method called:

```
-(NSData*)getSomeDataWithError:(NSError **)error;
```

I am using a synchronous NSURLConnection, my question is how do I wait for the connection to get the data when calling getSomeDataWithError?

Comment: If you are using a synchronous request, then it will block until the data is received. I don't understand what your problem is.

Comment: I start the connection in the init method of my class. This is a separate instance method that I call to get the data. I don't want to use delegation as a pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a synchronous request, your app will wait for the request to finish before it carries on executing any more code.

Also, I would have to ask why you are passing an `NSError` into your function? It makes no sense.